# Is there a way to share one master Calendar in iCloud?

Tags: objective-c, ios, icloud

I understand that I can use iCloud to sync Calendar (I'm assuming this is iCal) between multiple devices/users.

I have a requirement to have a *master calendar* that can be shared between users and automatically sync between those users.  All users must have the ability to add/update/delete entries.  And since I will be testing this, I don't want to use my personal iCal, so I need another group iCal stored on iCloud for testing, etc.

Is this possible with iOS and objective-c?  If so, which APIs would I be most interested in to accomplish this?

UPDATE:  each change to the "master calendar" is synced by iCloud, assuming the user devices are "registered" with iCloud. I need ONE calendar stored in ONE iCloud account, available to all "registered" users/devices. The app is going to access that calendar for back-end processing. The changes the users make to the calendar will be processed by the app when it is running (app is running during business hours, users can make changes 24/7)

Comment: "I understand that I can use iCloud to sync Calendar (I'm assuming this is iCal) between multiple devices/users." can you give more info on your assumption here? iCloud is an individual service, not for sharing between users. What sort of sharing are you thinking about?

Comment: See http://www.apple.com/icloud/features/calendar-contacts-mail.html which implies others can share the Calendar.  I have an app that has a calendar that takes the Calendar data, massages it and then displays the metrics.  I need supervisors and employees to be able to see everything on the Calendar, which iCloud supposedly will allow by syncing all devices.

Comment: I stand corrected! Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calendars and events in iOS are accessed using the [Event Kit Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EventKitFrameworkRef/_index.html). The user will have to have set up their iCloud account and calendar access/sharing separately, I don't think you can do this from within a third-party app.

Comment: That won't work... there has to be ONE iCloud account and ONE iCal calendar for this to work the way I need it to.  With one calendar and one iCloud account, iCloud will do the sync'ing to all of the user devices, which is what I need.

Comment: I don't understand you. iCloud syncing isn't done by your app. Your app connects to calendars available on the device, as configured by the user. If that calendar is synced via iCloud, the changes to it made by your app are as well.

Comment: I am aware of that... please see update to my question above.

Comment: I have decided to take another approach... Google Calendar..thank you for your time, I appreciate it.